# How do I tell how much I've made from a console?

Tags: game-dev-story

I dropped ~$100 mil on a console in Game Dev story, have 34% market share, and have sold 1.4 million units. However, can I somehow tell how much I've directly made from sales and licensing fees paid to my company? I'm trying to see how much of my investment I've regained. I can't find this figure anywhere.